# sending custom values to connect compatible middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I have an Express server and I'm trying to write some middleware that checks to see if a user is of the specified level, but I am at a loss on how to pass a `level` value to the middleware.

example app.js:

```
app.get('/restricted',verify.auth('4') , routes.index);
```

example auth.js

```
exports.verify = function(req, res, next, requiredLevel) {
    if(userLevel>=requiredLevel){next};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
verify.auth=function(requiredLevel){
 return function(req,res,next){
  // requiredLevel is visible here ..
  // manipulate req,res
   //..
  // call next middleware
  next();
 }
}
```

also working with sessions so you don't leave the user level to be specified by user..

Comment: And how would i define the required level in app.js?

Comment: call the middleware for a route `app.get('ROUTE',verify.auth('24') , ..);` or add the middleware to each route with http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use - `app.use()`